# Doctrine without setters

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I have been reading about Domain Driven Design and that entities should not have setters. It makes sense to pass the properties in the constructor, so the object is solid. Is there a way to use Doctrine ORM with this practice?

```
class User
{
    private $firstname;

    public function __construct($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }
}
```

How can Doctrine deal with this setup? Any drawbacks?

Comment: It will work just fine.  Doctrine does not use the constructor when hydrating objects from the database so there will be no conflicts.  The only problem is how to update the entity from say a form input.

Comment: @Cerad, would you know how to update an existing entity without setters? I tried `em->persist()` but it does not work (constraint on id) and `em->merge()` is deprecated.

Comment: @Kwadz A blast from the past.  Not sure what your question is.  Might be best to open a new question.  This particular question makes the common mistake that DDD entities are the same as Doctrine entities.  They are in fact two very different creatures.  If you feel the urge to update Doctrine entities then use setters or use public properties.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will come across many drawbacks, like:

- ID is available after persist => solution: using object ids or UUID in entity constructor

  - for more see: https://carlosbuenosvinos.com/doctrine-25-ddd-entities-and-identities/
- Symfony forms like to use setters => solution: use constructor (as you do) and CQRS

  - for more see:

    - http://verraes.net/2013/04/decoupling-symfony2-forms-from-entities/
    - https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/
- value objects (like Email object that validates email in it's constructor) => solution: use embeddables

  - for more see: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html